# Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1527217399000"

Tags: java, date

I got some values

```
"createTime": 1527217399000,
"updateTime": 1527218049000,

"createTime": 1527217399000,
"updateTime": 1527217954000,
```

But I can not parse them to date format, I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the data format,is there any method to parse them?

```
SimpleDateFormat format =  new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" );
Long tempTime = 1527217399000L;
Date createDate=format.parse(tempTime.toString());
    System.out.println(createDate.toString());

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 
"1527217399000"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
```

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: guys, I fixed it by transferring  the Timestamp to Date first

Comment: You shouldn’t post the solution in the question, rather than as an answer, please. You may even accept your own answer (after a while). We can find our way around here easier when the question is where the question belongs and the answers where the answers belong.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a `Date` instance from a `long` value, use:

```
Date createDate=new Date(tempTime);
```

As the Javadoc mentions:

> j**ava.util.Date.Date(long date)**
>
> Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

`SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" )` is meant to parse a `String` of the specified format into a `Date` (i.e. if you wanted to parse a `String` such as "2018-05-28 06:12:00" into a `Date` instance).

Comment: I also just found this solution. LOL

Answer (score 2):

Since it's 2018, you really should be making use of the `java.time` API introduced in Java 8

```
long createTime = 1527217399000L;
LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(createTime).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
String format = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH));
System.out.println(format);
```

Which prints `2018-05-25 13:03:19` (on PC)

And if you don't have Java 8, there's the [ThreeTen backport](http://www.threeten.org) which makes the API available to earlier versions of Java

Answer (score 2):

The old java.util.Date API is notoriously poor and if you want to make clear decisions about what type of date / time you're using - whether it's in a particular timezone, etc. - you should use the java.time API.

Assuming (you'd need to confirm) that these millisecond timestamps are in UTC timezone, you can use code like this to format it as a date/time in your local system timezone.

```
Long tempTime = 1527217399000L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(tempTime);
ZonedDateTime dateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
```